# c# - wp - convert image to grayscale according to slider value

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, windows-phone, grayscale

I'm trying to convert image from colored into grayscale but the grayscale level is depended on the slider level. Most of the tutorial I found in internet is making it into absolute grayscale. Thanks for your answers, I very appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use some interpolation between full-color image and grayscale version with coefficient determined by the slider's value.
For example, if you convert to grayscale using `ColorMatrix`, as [described here](http://tech.pro/tutorial/660/csharp-tutorial-convert-a-color-image-to-grayscale#short_and_sweet), then, to get partially grayed image, you should apply interpolated matrix. Say, "slider=0" is full-color and "slider=1" is grayscale, then the matrix to apply is defined:

```
<color_matrix_to_apply> = slider * <grayscale_matrix> + (1 - slider) * <identity_matrix>
```

As `ColorMatrix` does not provide ariphmetic operations, you should implement this formula "manually", for each item of the matrices.

```
matrixToApply.Matrix00 = slider * grayscaleMatrix.Matrix00 + (1 - slider) * identityMatrix.Matrix00;
...
matrixToApply.Matrix44 = slider * grayscaleMatrix.Matrix44 + (1 - slider) * identityMatrix.Matrix44;
```